# Ektron cms add the / symbol in content title

Tags: ektron

I am created a new html content and enter the content title like this 'Example 1 / Example 2' after click  the publish button it shows the error msg like does not allow the symbol <>/. But i need to add the / in content title. If its any possible way to do that friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in the Content Title.  You might want to consider creating a Smartform with a Title field, which will allow that character.

Comment: +1 don't use the content title for display purposes if you can help it; just as a user-friendly identifier.

Answer (score 0):

This used to work in version 8.02 I believe. It was actually fixed in version 9.1 SP1 in the latest update that was released so it should now work again.